# automated tests as a user?

Tags: php, users, login, testing

I checked out (with svn) the code for [Automated Testing](http://codex.wordpress.org/Automated_Testing). However, I want to run unit tests as a specific user.

Is there a way to do that? That is, is there a way to loggin with php code alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$user_id = $this->_make_user('author', 'user_login_name', 'password', 'test@test.com');
wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
```

as long as the class that you define the testcase in inherits from `WPTestCase`, then you can use the `_make_user` function. The function is found in [this svn repository](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-tests/), and is defined in `wp-testlib/base.php` line 380.

NEW:

I switched to using `wp_insert_user`.

the following is in my setUp:

```
    $this->user_id = wp_insert_user(array('user_login'=>'test_administrator', 'role'=>'administrator'));
    wp_set_current_user( $this->user_id , '');
```

and the following is in my teardown:

```
    wp_delete_user($this->user_id);
    $this->user_id = 0;
```